# display data in the form of a table using Ajax

Tags: python, ajax, mongodb

I have the below code in Ajax to display the data from python stored in MongoDB.

```
<script>
function f(){
$(document).ready(function(){
          $.get('ajax1', function(result){ 
          $.each(result, function(index, element) {
          alert(JSON.stringify(element));
           });
       });
    });
  }
</script>
```

Python call for the same:

```
@route('/ajax1')
def func():
    client = MongoClient()
    db = client.collection
    result = db.collection.find({},{'_id':0}).limit(2) 
    arr = []
    for document in result:
        arr.append(doc)


  return (dict(items=arr))
```

I am getting the result as below:
  `[{"Name":"abc","Place":"SomePlace","Designation":"des"}]`
  `[{"Name":"NextName","Place":"NextPlace","Designation":"Nextdes"}]`

I want to print it in this format or in the form of a table:

`abc Someplace des`
`NextName Nextplace Nextdes`

Can somebody tell me how to do it? Seems simple but I am unaware of it.
Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

To me it would make more sense to use the property names in the javascript as it's easier to understand and more verbose.

```
<script>
function f(){
  $(document).ready(function(){
    $.get('ajax1', function(result){ 
       $.each(result, function(index, element) {
          var row = element.Name + " " + element.Place + " " + element.Designation;
          console.log(row);
       });
    });
  });
}
</script>
```

Comment: when I do this, I'm getting the result as undefined undefined undefined for each value. Any suggestions on how to make it proper?? @schillingt

Comment: Take a look at what's being returned from the server. The names or structure of what's being returned are probably different.

Comment: It is showing like this, @schillingt                                                                `{"items:[{"Name":"abc","Place":"SomePlace","Designation":"des"},{"Name":"NextName","Place":"NextPlace","Designation":"Nextdes"}]}`

Comment: Use a debugger and determine why it's undefined.

Comment: Could you tell me how can I display a field named  "Unique Name" `element.Unique Name ` doesn't work as there is a space in between. @ schillingt

Comment: ```element["Unique Name"]```